# What is the nuclear/trace norm of a single block matrix?

Tags: trace, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

Given a matrix $X$ which has the following form: $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, where $A$ is again some matrix. How does the nuclear/trace norm of $||X||_{\text{tr}}$ relate to $||A||_{\text{tr}}$?

---

Can I say that they are equal because there exists some permutation matrix such that A i.e. is the upper left hand block. Furthermore permutation matrices are unitary and the Schatten norms are unitarily invariant which means $||X||_{\text{tr}} = ||A||_{\text{tr}}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach with the permutation matrix works out. An alternative argument would be to just use the definition.

Namely, by definition we have

\begin{align*}
\Vert X \Vert_\mathrm{tr} = \mathrm{tr}(\sqrt{X^* X}).
\end{align*}
However,
\begin{align*}
X^* X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ A^* & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A^* A \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{X^* X} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{A^* A} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
and therefore
\begin{align*}
\Vert X \Vert_\mathrm{tr} = \mathrm{tr}(\sqrt{X^* X}) = \mathrm{tr}(\sqrt{A^* A}) = \Vert A \Vert_\mathrm{tr}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

If $A = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i \boldsymbol{u}_i\boldsymbol{v}^*_i$, then

\begin{align}
X &= \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf O & A\\
\mathbf O & \mathbf O 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf O & \boldsymbol{u}_i\boldsymbol{v}_i^*\\
\mathbf O & \mathbf O 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{u}_{i}\\
\boldsymbol{0}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{0} &
\boldsymbol{v}^*_{i}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

This is the SVD of $X$ and clearly $X$ and $A$ have the same signular values.